# Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: linux, blockchain, metamask, hardhat

I am setting up hardhat in Linux. I have set up the react app first using these commands.

```
npx create-react-app react-dapp

cd react-dapp
```

Then I have installed some hardhat dependencies using this command.

```
npm install ethers hardhat @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle \
        ethereum-waffle chai \
        @nomiclabs/hardhat-ether
```

This all done correctly.
Then I have created the hardhat configs and setup.

```
npx hardhat
```

Then I have edited the **hardhat.config.js** file.
I have places this.

```js
module.exports = {
    solidity: "0.8.4",
    paths: {                         
       artifacts: './src/artifacts',  
    },
    networks: {                 
      hardhat: {
       chainId: 1337                
     }
   }
 };
```

After that I have created the node.

```
npx hardhat node
```

I got this error:

> **Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported**

Answer (score 27):

Had the same problem. Using Node 17.x and it has an updated openssl that is a a breaking change.

This worked for me because I'm using yarn.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

You could also try just using the `--openssl-legacy-provider` switch on node.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve the problem using lts node version using nvm.

```
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact problem just now, however since I have nvm, my cheap work around is to used node v16 for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem running node 18.10.0
and was able to fix it with [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXHWk.png)

and then running this command "npm install --save-dev hardhat"

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. However, updating the package.json file worked for me. You will have to update "scripts/start" dependency as shown in the image below:[image]

`start:"export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npx hardhat node"`

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:
"npm update --legacy-peer-deps"