# Error running hardhat node: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, chainlink, hardhat

tried running `npx hardhat node`

this is the error I got

```
Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH604 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
```

here is my config file.

```js
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const KOVAN_RPC_URL = process.env.KOVAN_RPC_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    kovan: {
      url: KOVAN_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.0",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 20000
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69671888/11969592

Comment: It totally worked!! I'll mark this question as duplicate. And try to search harder before posting a question. The Hackathon is so cool. Patrick Collins fielding questions. You are the best. Very approachable!!!

Comment: Awesome :) Great work! If you could upvote that question too so others can be routed there, that would be great.

Comment: It's not working anymore. I don't know why. I was pasting that command right in the terminal. Am I supposed to insert that code into some config file?

Comment: are you getting the same error?

Comment: It works now. Before the hardhat command I paste: export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider. But is there a way to insert this into the package.json. someone told me this is possible and I followed their instructions but it didn't work.

Comment: it works. sorry that was a different error preventing me from moving forward. Both fixed Yaaay! but something is up with my Tasks logic lol. I'm going to do the workshop over. This is my third time... excited tho and I will keep trying.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-951378874

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer or edit it if it is correct

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you need to update your `package.json` with `export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npx hardhat node"
  },
```

Then, you can just run `yarn start` or `export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npx hardhat node`

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-951378874