# Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Unknown transaction type 106

Tags: openssl, fork, solidity, hardhat

I try to fork mainnet by running `yarn hardhat node` and I get that error.
`Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Unknown transaction type 106`

My **hardhat.config.js** file has forking settings.

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
      forking: {
        url: process.env.ARBITRUM_RPC_URL,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I have tried edit my `package.json` based on [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69748147/18073055) and run `yarn start`.

After that, I get `--openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS` error. I have tried to downgrade Node to `v16` but I get still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Going to cross-link this here: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/2995

This issue is actively being worked on but there seems to be a patch available.

Comment: This was fixed in Hardhat v2.12.2.